# CakePHP 2.1 doesn't work on localhost

Tags: mysql, cakephp, localhost, cakephp-2.1

I deployed my app on a remote host and everything works as expected. But when I try to test my code on localhost, it gives me the following error, without any change to the code working on the host:

`Fatal error: Class 'AppHelper' not found in [path]`

I am using CakePHP 2.1 and MySQL as my default datasource.

I connect to my local database just like to the remote one (with authentication changes):

```
public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'database',
    'prefix' => '',
    'encoding' => 'utf8',
);
```

Why isn't this working on my localhost? Thank you

Comment: It is possible that you have a helper that is't in $helpers array in the Controller ?? Or a wrong route for a helper

Comment: My helpers array looks like `public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session', 'Js', 'Text', 'Time');`. Anyway, the thing is that on my remote host the same code works fine.

Comment: then verify your routes... remote != localhost ... it's another environment :) Anyway.. have a class that is extends in AppHelper ? (verify in helpers) If you have, change it in Helper. Teoreticaly, this erros is caused by two problems, wrong route or missing helper in helpers folder

Comment: I don't have any custom helper. The only route I've added is `Router::parseExtensions('json');`, because I need the JsonView. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Add 'Json' to the $helpers array in the Controller because you don't have it and check your App::uses('AppHelper', 'View/Helper') for eliminate 'uses' problem

Comment: I've added the Json to the helpers and still the same issue. Regarding the other part, where to check the App::uses()?

Comment: doesn't matter .. is't in a core.. it must be right. what is the [path] ? paste please first 20 lines from that helper (i suppose it's a json helper...)

Comment: Please, switch to debug 2 and post full stack trace.

Comment: Figured it out. I was missing the AppHelper file from my app. I thought it was included in the Cake core. Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two possible things:
either you didnt know about the AppHelper requirement for 2.1:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-1-migration-guide.html

or you forget to declare the helper at the very top of your class:

```
 App::uses('AppHelper', 'View/Helper');
```

Although the second one is highly unlikely if you are not running any unit tests.
So my bet is on the first one.

Comment: That's right, I figured it out already, have posted in the question's comments :) Thank you anyway!

Comment: Ah, ok. But you should add the uses statement to your helper file, as well. It will break on test cases, otherwise.

Comment: I don't have any custom helper files. This is what I added in the `AppHelper.php`: `App::uses('Helper', 'View'); class AppHelper extends Helper {}`